# kdtigetrow-2 error during integration

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sqlplus, ora-00600

I am facing this error, and due to this error, the whole system seems to be going down. After checking logs and all, I found out that one destination tables might be the problem.

This is the error:

```
MERGE INTO vacations vac
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kdtigetrow-2], [25], [40], [39],
[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

This is the source table:

```
    create table TEMP_VACATIONS
(
  idd       VARCHAR2(10),
  start_date   VARCHAR2(10),
  end_date     VARCHAR2(10),
  day_count    VARCHAR2(10),
  vac_type     VARCHAR2(10),
  arrival_date DATE
)
```

This is the destination table:

```
    create table VACATIONS
    (
      user_id       NUMBER(10) not null,
      start_date    DATE not null,
      end_date      DATE not null,
      days_count    NUMBER(3) not null,
      vacation_type INTEGER,
      arrival_date  VARCHAR2(20),
      idd        NUMBER(10)
    )
    alter table SPENT_VACATIONS
  add constraint SPENT_VACATIONS$PK primary key (USER_ID, START_DATE)
  using index 
  tablespace ARCV25
  pctfree 10
  initrans 2
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 320K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
```

and this is the script:

```
MERGE INTO vacations vac
    USING temp_vacations tmpvac
    ON (vac.user_id = TO_NUMBER(tmpvac.idd) AND vac.start_date = TO_DATE(tmpvac.start_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy') AND vac.end_date = TO_DATE(tmpvac.end_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy'))
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
         INSERT (vac.user_id, vac.start_date, vac.end_date, vac.days_count, vac.vacation_type, vac.arrival_date)
         VALUES (TO_NUMBER(tmpvac.idd), TO_DATE(tmpvac.start_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy'), TO_DATE(tmpvac.end_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy'), tmpvac.day_count, tmpvac.vac_type, TO_CHAR(tmpvac.arrival_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy'))
    LOG ERRORS INTO stara.migration_err('File: STARA_EHR.SPOLO.TXT => merge operation => annual_vacations')  REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
COMMIT;
```

The oracle version is:

```
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.2.0
```

Is it possible that this error comes during type conversation (char => date or char => number) ?

How can I fix that internal error as well? Do I need to rollback the database to previous backup?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The internal error means that statement failed because of a bug, you don't need to restore your database. The only bug I can see seems to involve pipelined table functions, which you aren't using. The type conversions shouldn't be a problem - I can run this (in 11.2.0.3) without problems, but I'm inventing the data obviously; and I've assumed you have the same PK on `vacations` as you've shown as being on `spent_vacations`?

Answer (score 3):

ORA-00600 is Oracle's generic code for signalling unexpected internal behaviour (i.e. bugs).  The standard advice is to contact Oracle Support, as by the nature of these things, they tend to be very specific to database version, platform and a whole host of other variables.  There is a distinct possibility that you need a patch to fix this problem, or perhaps just an upgrade to the latest version.

Of course, if you don't have a Support contract that advice is not very useful.  Unfortunately it's hard for us to be more helpful.  There should be further information in the Alert Log, and there may be a trace file too.  You'll probably have to ask a DBA to help you with it.

Otherwise you can try searching the internet.  The first parameter indicates the specific event i.e. `[kdtigetrow-2]`.  I did find t[his article on a blog](http://arjudba.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/ora-00600-kdtigetrow-2-or-kddummyblkchk.html) but the writer's scenario appears to be very different from your own.

Answer (score 2):

We have upgraded the Oracle db to 11.2.0.3 with latest patch 21. Now all is working good :-)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an index corruption. Disable the constraint, drop the index, recreate the index and enable the constraint again.